# Clarification on Unawarded Bounties

Tags: support, bounty

So I answered a question after a bounty was placed: [Bug with adjusting RTF in Winforms when using Windows-wide beta UTF-8 support feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56382753/495455)

I get the most upvotes.

I get more than 2 upvotes, 4 more votes than another answer.

The Auto-Bounty goes to the answer with 3 votes compared to my 7 votes and that was answered well after mine.

I have enough bounties, that's not the point, **let's NOT change anything** I don't want the meta-effect. My question is, is this a bug? Or what am I not understanding as to why my answer didn't get the Auto-Bounty?

Comment: Did you post your answer after the bounty started?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan Turns out I asked the right question. The user posted his answer *before* the bounty he’s asking about was posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question had two bounties. You posted your answer while the first bounty was active, but the answer wasn't eligible for automatic awarding.

The [question revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56382753/revisions) shows this:

> Bounty Started worth 50 reputation by Dan W   occurred Jun 1 at 22:42
>   Bounty Ended with no winning answer by Community♦     occurred Jun 10 at 0:03
>   Bounty Started worth 100 reputation by Dan W  occurred Jun 18 at 13:02
>   Bounty Ended with SreedharMV's answer chosen by Community♦    occurred 22 hours ago

Your answer was posted on Jun 3 at 0:26, SreedharMV's answer was posted on Jun 24 at 3:22.

Comment: You are right and I'm OK with that. The other guy did deserve it more.

Comment: @Jeremy By Jun 10, when the first bounty ended, your answer [had received only one upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56419955/timeline), and thus wasn't eligible.